# redirect files with .htm extension "inside a subfolder" to the .php extension

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I changed all files from `.htm` to `.php` inside a subfolder.
Is this the correct way to redirect all files with `.htm` extension inside the subfolder to the .php extension instead?

```
RedirectMatch 301 /subfolder/(.*)\.htm$ http://example.com$1.php
```

(I combined the following two)

```
#Redirect a sub folder to another site
Redirect 301 /subfolder http://www.example.com/

#This will redirect any file with the .html extension to use the same filename but use the .php extension instead.
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://www.example.com$1.php
```

Comment: Why are doing `Redirect a sub folder to another site` ?

Comment: "I changed all files from `.htm` to `.php` inside a subfolder" - _and_ moved them to the document root?

Comment: Also the directive will result in a broken URL: the leading slash in the path is not captured, thus missing in the target of the redirection.

Comment: A side note: what sense does a "file name extension ".htm"" make? Is it still 1975?